# Why did Aoi-sensei expect Shouko to leave with Nami?

Tags: aoishiro

in the Grand Route of Aoishiro, after arriving on Urashima with Nami Shouko gets a call from Aoi-sensei who asks where they are.

After finding out that Shouko is on Urashima she also confirms if Nami is when her saying she figured Shouko would take Nami there with her.

i don't get this though, in all other routes when Nami goes missing and Shouko is Urashima with her the usual reasoning is that Shouko went looking for her and found her on Urashima. Also since Yasuhime-sama had only just retried her power from the Tsubaki Tree out the back of Shoushinji which resulted in Nami's voice returning and right after Shouko and Nami leave for Urashima, no one from Seijou would have known of any connection between the Tsubaki Tree and Nami

So i am wondering why Aoi-sensei expected Shouko to have left for Urashima with Nami?